# Доступно мало оперативной памяти

Tags: windows-7

При запуске пк, он начал виснуть.Кое-как зашёл в «Мой компьютер» и увидел, что из 6гб оперативной памяти, доступен 1.10 гб.
Windows 7 домашняя расширенная.  64-разрядная.
Через mscofig пробовал.

Comment: 1.Проверь комп на вирусы. 2.Зайди в диспетчер задач посмотри какое приложение берет столько оперативки.

Comment: Недоступная память занята приложениями (какими?) или зарезервирована системой? Что вы через msconfig пробовали?

Comment: Если вирусов нет, **1.** Попробуйте установить [**Process Hacker**](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) → откройте его и посмотрите, какие программы/сервисы имеют наибольшие значения в [**разделах CPU и Private bytes**](https://i.imgur.com/C9fbmaX.png). Запомните программы/сервисы с наибольшими показателями.

Comment: **2.** Установите и запустите [**AutoRuns**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/AutoRuns) → снимите галочки с приложений/сервисов, которые потребляют много памяти (см. мой предыдущий комментарий). Можете [**снимать галочки**](https://i.imgur.com/eUD85KE.png) со всех программ/сервисов, которые Вам не нужны, но если не уверены, что делает какая-либо программа/сервис/библиотека, лучше не снимайте для неё галочку во избежание проблем с системой.

Comment: 3. Установите и запустите [**Wise Memory Optimizer**](http://www.wisecleaner.com/wise-memory-optimizer.html) → настройте [**авто-оптимизацию**](https://i.imgur.com/ylDUymf.png). Если значение свободной оперативной памяти будет ниже, чем Вы указали в настройках, программа оптимизирует объём Вашей оперативной памяти.

Comment: *(Как ответ бы это опубликовать, но, чувствую, закрыватели сейчас придут)*.

Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных "закрыватели придут, значит пишем роман в комментариях" - что за логика? :) Хороший ответ как раз защищает закрытый вопрос от удаления духом, а комменты могут и снести как обычно. (Я бы плюсанул, если вместо ссылок на сомнительные утилиты было описание как выявит проблему, пользуясь стандартными средствами Windows + RAMMap Руссиновича)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: **1.** ПМСМ, у ответов качество должно быть выше, чем у комментариев. На ответы я обычно трачу времени куда больше, чем несколько минут. А если вопрос закроют и удалят — получится, что я потратил много времени зря. Комментарии же могут помочь автору вопроса. // **2.** Неплохо было бы как-то аргументировать «сомнительность» утилит. // **3.** `Хороший ответ как раз защищает закрытый вопрос от удаления духом` — тут поподробнее, если можно. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных закрытые вопросы с рейтингом <=0 и без ответов с положительным рейтингом автоматически удаляются через 9 дней (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba), поэтому если написать хороший ответ, можно спасти вопрос. Впрочем, если вопрос не заминусуют, он под автоудаление и так не попадет